# Flutter iOS Storage audio doesnt Play with audioplayer, fluttersound and just audio

Tags: ios, flutter, audio, flutter-ios

I am working on an app that can record voice and play from storage. I have tried all these packages and get errors only on real iOS devices. On emulator side there is no issue on ios too. I am recording audio with flutter [flutter_sound](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_sound).

directory is

```
tempDir = await getTemporaryDirectory();
```

recording;

```
  startRecorderx(
  FlutterSoundRecorder flutterSoundRecorder, Directory? tempDir) async {
log(tempDir!.path.toString());
PermissionStatus status;
try {
  status = await Permission.microphone.request();
} catch (e) {
  throw e;
}
log(tempDir.path.toString());

if (status != PermissionStatus.granted)
  throw RecordingPermissionException("You must give acces to mic");
pathToRecord =
    "${tempDir.path}/${DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch.toString()}.aac";

await flutterSoundRecorder.startRecorder(
  toFile: "$pathToRecord",
  codec: Codec.aacADTS,
);
```

}

Then i can not play this file from path netiher 3 packages audioplayers, [flutter_sound](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_sound).

```
     play(path) async {
    File file = File(path);
    Uint8List bytes =  file.readAsBytesSync();
     await audio.play(path);
    //log(result.toString());
    /* await flutterSoundPlayer.startPlayer(
       //fromURI: "$path",
       fromDataBuffer: bytes,
     ) ;*/
    update();
  }
```

I got error from [flutter_sound](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_sound) only.

```
PlatformException (PlatformException(Audio Player, startPlayer failure, null, null))
```

Comment: Did you follow the instalation instructions? There are some descriptions you may have to add to info.plist, as you can see [here](https://flutter-sound.canardoux.xyz/flutter_sound_install.html#post-installation)

Comment: yes I have added and it is working fine on ios emulator, doesnt work on only ios real device

Comment: same here , did you find any solution ?

Comment: no, unfortunatelly :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with path. iOS returns always different paths. They masks directory's path for 'security' I guess. If you are storing full path of a file you can get real path with the function, it is my case and substringing your path depends on your case, please mind your case;

where applicationDocumentDirectory saves file ;
/Users/alperenbaskaya/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/D3C845C6-D8CE-40FA-9060-1D8062E7F597/data/Containers/Data/Application/17501EFE-57A4-4C71-8C4C-58BBC57D1177/Documents/1661040154934.jpg

then my operation is that;

```
  Future<String> getCurrentUrl(String url)async{
    if(Platform.isIOS){
    String a = url.substring(url.indexOf("Documents/") + 10, url.length) ;
    Directory dir = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    a = "${dir.path}/$a";
    return a;
    }
    else{
      return url;
    }
  }
```

Answer (score -2):

For iOS just add file:// before directory path

Directory dir = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();

String fullUrl = "file://${dir.path}/MP3-FILE-NAME";